# Old IP displayed in route table after Ubuntu image clone on new server

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, resolv.conf

I have cloned an existing Ubuntu image off of our AWS server, upgraded to 20.04, and am trying to configure the connection to the outside world. I've been running into a lot issues on the frontend where I would get 401 authentication failures every time I would try to log in via the web interface.

I did some digging and a lot of googling, and I found that the server was trying to resolve to the old server, instead of the new one.

**Old Server IP =** 172.9.8.7

**New Server IP =** 172.1.2.3

When I run `route -n` on my **new** server I see the following:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.9.8.7      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.9.8.7      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

So I did some googling on some forums and found that the `resolve.conf` file was pointing to the wrong one. I changed it to point to this: `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` which had the old server IP where I modified it to the new one.

I then restarted the `resolvconf` service and see this:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-1-2-3: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Running `ifconfig` shows the correct server IP. `ufw` is also disabled, and `iptables` is empty as this is the configuration of the live server.

What am I missing here? I can't seem to figure out why the physical server local ip is being rejected.

Server is running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: @chili555 that directory is empty

Comment: How are you managing networking in this server if not netplan? With nmcli? Or what??

Comment: Not sure. This was cloned off a 16.04 ubuntu server. It looks like I may have to configure a netplan. Not sure how to do that, but I can look that up.

Comment: If cloned from 16.04, you might find the details in `/etc/network/interfaces` Please edit your question to give the details if you get stuck. You can find example templates in `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples`